# Function assignment doesn't work

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm new to Node.js. I have searched the forum but couldn't find a similar question. Here is the problem I encountered. The following code runs fine.

```
process.stdout.write("hello world!\n");
```

but the following code:

```
var myprint = process.stdout.write;
myprint("hello world");
```

will generate the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'defaultEncoding' of undefined
```

Any suggestions? Thank you so much.

Comment: What happens if you write `myprint.apply(process.stdout, ["hello world"])`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably, the `write()` method needs to be called with the correct object reference so the `write()` method knows what stream it is writing to.  There are multiple ways to work around this.  Here's one way:

```
var myprint = process.stdout.write.bind(process.stdout);
myprint("hello world");
```

See [`.bind()` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) for more info.

For future reference, when you do:

```
var myprint = process.stdout.write;
```

`myprint` only contains a reference to the `write` method and that method is then called with no object reference.  That means that the `this` pointer inside the `write()` method will not point at the stdout stream like it would when you call it as `process.stdout.write()`.  If a method needs it's instance data (which most methods do), then this creates a problem.  You can "bind" the object reference to a new temporary function using `.bind()` which allows you to assign it to another variable and then use it directly like you were attempting to do.

Answer (score 2):

The `write` function is trying to access a variable on the `this` variable, which is not set to `process.stdout` when you call `myprint`, unlike when you call `process.stdout.write`.

Note that

```
var out = process.stdout;
out.print('wow\n');
```

will work as expected.